# Why is MySQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP returning odd values like '%qd' in MySQL 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unix-timestamp

I am attempting to query time data from MySQL in PHP, using this sort of method:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_ADD( a.`date_time`, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) * 1000 AS time FROM `graph_values` AS a
```

On a production server running MySQL 5.0.x, this returns a unix timestamp as expected.  However, on a development server running MySQL 5.5.x it returns a string `"%qd"`.  I attempted to `CAST` the result to an unsigned integer following some of the suggestions in the MySQL documentation on this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

When I cast the result of the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function as an `UNSIGNED`, the query returned a different string, `"%qu"`.

So, its obvious that the odd string is influenced by datatype of the data being returned, but I've never seen PHP/MySQL behave this way.

Note:  This is using PHP and mysqli.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you multiply a timestamp with 1000?

Comment: The returned data is eventually passed via JSON to a JavaScript framework that requires a timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: Does it work without this multiplication?

Comment: Surprisingly, it does.  It would be possible to refactor the application to perform the multiplication in PHP but I would prefer to keep the logic in MySQL, especially considering it works just fine under a different MySQL version.  Do you have any suggestions on how I could restructure the query to retain the multiplication logic?  Thanks for your suggestion, it did not occur to me that the math was interfering with my results.

Comment: Are you on a 32bit PHP? today's timestamp * 1000 exceeds the 2^31-1 max_int size in 32bit PHP by a considerable amount.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for Mac, which appears to be 32bit only.  That may be the real source of my problem.  I will move to using the native PHP and 64bit MySQL for OSX and see if that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting the result to some other type (signed int, decimal)?

If everything goes wrong - you may be able to use something like FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%s');
to "cast" it in another way.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Not something I would want to have in my production code though...

Comment: Finally getting around to following up on this--casting the result as a string did cause the code to run correctly in my 32 bit environment, but I agree with you that I wouldn't run that sort of code in production.  So, at the end of the day, this was the solution for my development environment only.  The problem did not exist in production anyway, because my production stack is 64 bit.  Thanks!